# построение грида и имена полей

Tags: angularjs

Строю грид на основе JSON. Что-то вроде такого

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td>[{{$index + 1}}]  {{person.id}}</td>
    <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Вопрос в следующем: в данном коде я обращаюсь к полям коллекции напрямую (person.firstName). Что делать, если неизвестно название i-того поля? Возможно ли обратиться вроде person.fields[i]? Существует ли такой синтаксис в ангуляре?

Далее можно усложнить задачу: количество полей неизвестно (т.е. количество тэгов td, которые требуется сгенерировать динамически)

**UPD**

```
JSON: [
    {"id": "1",    "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jhons"},
    {"id": "2",    "firstName": "Marcus", "lastName": "Smith"},
    {"id": "3",    "firstName": "Grotter", "lastName": "Changer"}
]
```

должно получиться:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id </th> <th>firstName </th> <th>lastName </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1<td> <td>‌​Peter</td><td>Jhons </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
     <td>2<td> <td>‌​Marcus</td><td>Smith </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
     <td>1<td> <td>‌​Grotter</td><td>Changer </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
```

Comment: больше строчек нужно в примере, в JSON 3 строки, добавь их все в html,

Comment: строчка с `th` должна быть одна? или перед каждой персоной выводить его поля?

Comment: да, строка с th одна

Comment: то есть набор полей у всех объектов одинаковый

Comment: да, на данном этапе задача такая

Comment: а вот кстати, как насчёт порядка полей? насколько я понял из доков к ангуляру (может я ошибаюсь) он может не совпадать с порядком полей в JSON, причём ещё в разных браузерах может быть разный?

Comment: на примере в ответе я сохранил поля в отдельный массив, и его можно отсортировать так как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) работает как с массивами, так и с объектами

В случае массива выражение может выглядеть так

```
variable in expression
```

где `variable` - это значение конкретного элемента массива.

В случае объектов

```
(key, value) in expression
```

где `key` - это имя поля, а `value` - это значение поля.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.people = [{
      id: 1,
      lastName: 'Иванов'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      lastName: 'Петров',
      firstName: 'Петр'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      lastName: 'Кузнецов',
      firstName: 'Кузнец',
      middleName: 'Кузнецович'
    }];

  });
```

```css
.people {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.id {
  width: 10%
}
.lastName {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%
}
.firstName {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%
}
.middleName {
  background-color: blue;
  color:yellow;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as c">
  <div class="people" ng-repeat="person in c.people">
    <div class="{{k}}" ng-repeat="(k,v) in person">{{k}} - {{v}}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

<sub>в случае когда на каждой строчке может быть разное количество ячеек, скорее всего не нужно использовать таблицу, которая как раз подразумевает *одинаковое* количество ячеек в каждой строке</sub>

**Обновление**

В случае когда отдельной строкой нужно вывести имена полей, проще всего сохранить их в отдельную переменную, которую потом использовать

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.people = [{
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jhons"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Marcus",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "firstName": "Grotter",
      "lastName": "Changer"
    }];
    this.fields = Object.keys(this.people[0]); //получаем ключи из первого объекта

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as c">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="field in c.fields">{{field}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="people" ng-repeat="person in c.people">
      <td ng-repeat="field in c.fields">{{person[field]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем то. Хотелось бы получить table вида <tr><td>id</td><td>firstName</td><td>lastName</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Иван</td><td>Иванов</td></tr> и т.д. Т.е. чтобы первым tr шли названия полей

Comment: для упрощения задачи предположим, что количество полей во всех элементах массива одинаковое

Comment: @user211576, добавь в вопрос пример данных и конечной разметки, сейчас не совсем понятно что должно в итого получиться

Comment: ну вот например такой JSON [
{"id": "1",    "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jhons"},
{"id": "2",    "firstName": "Marcus", "lastName": "Smith"},
{"id": "3",    "firstName": "Grotter", "lastName": "Changer"}
]

Comment: @user211576, отредактируй **вопрос** добавив в него входные данные, и ожидаемую разметку по ним

Comment: должно получиться <table><tr><th>id</th><th>firstName</th><th>lastName</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Peter</td><td>Jhons</td></tr> ну и т. д.

Comment: ok, дописал  upd

Comment: @user211576, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Такое вроде как вполне работает, в том числе и для переменного количества полей в `person`:

```
// пусть people выглядит как-то так
people = 
    [
         {id: 1, lastName: 'Иванов'}
        ,{id: 2, lastName: 'Петров', firstName: 'Петр'}
        ,{id: 3, lastName: 'Кузнецов', firstName: 'Кузнец', middleName: 'Кузнецович'}
    ];
// ...
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td ng-repeat="p in person">{{p}}</td>
</tr>
```

Хотя не исключено, что с порядком вывода полей таким образом могут возникнуть неожиданности.

Comment: это, если не ошибаюсь, значение поля. а имя поля?

Comment: Значение, да.  Не уверен, что можно получить имена полей Но, честно говоря, затрудняюсь представить сценарий, в котором потребовались бы именно имена.